# Hot module replacement is not working for multiple configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr

I have created two configuration. One for client side and other for server side. I am trying to enable `HMR` - **Hot Module Replacement** for the client side but it is not working.

My Webpack configuration is:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const clientConfig = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/clients/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/client'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
                }
            }
        },{
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader'],
        },{
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "html-loader"
            }]
        }],
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/clients/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html'
    }), new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],

    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public/client'),
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        port: 8080
    }
}

const serverConfig = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/server/index.js',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/server'),
        filename: 'server.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
                }
            }
        }],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __isBrowser__: "false"
        })
    ]
}

module.exports = [clientConfig, serverConfig]
```

Also the `scripts` in the `package.json` are:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "server": "nodemon ./public/server/server.js",
    "client": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

> Note: When I try to export only one module from Webpack then HMR is working fine.

```
module.exports = clientConfig;
```

What am I missing when working with multiple configuration?